# Crontab - I have two cron jobs but only one works

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have created 2 cron jobs but only one works. The 2 different website building with drupal cms.

```
*/5 * * * * curl -s http://www.example.com/cron.php?cron_key=TzVesnZuNqR4mkjv_LgBemUV-oYvsfYalyHOfDtL4cc

*/5 * * * * curl -s http://www.example.gr/cron.php?cron_key=OrrbXhtfSEZ2NI7BlHjAPRtMT_ENAKaz68iH86Kl5wI
```

In `/var/log/syslog`, I get `cron could not run because an invalid key was used`, but my key is correct. When I launch manually, cron runs successfully.

I don't understand why this happens. Is there any solution?

Comment: You should find log entries in /var/log/syslog related to CRON which can help diagnose what's going on.

Comment: This can be anything. From the wrong key to the broken cron.php script. What happens when you launch commands manually?

Comment: when i launch manually, run cron successfully. 
In syslog i get "Cron could not run because an invalid key was used." but my key is correct

Comment: also create cron on setcronjob.com and run cron successfully! The problem rather is in ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do? The commands you configured normally print the requested website on screen. But cron has no "screen".

I would recommed you do something like this to catch the output and investigate it:

```
*/5 * * * * curl -s http://www.example.com/cron.php?cron_key=TzVesnZuNqR4mkjv_LgBemUV-oYvsfYalyHOfDtL4cc > /tmp/job1.log
*/5 * * * * curl -s http://www.example.gr/cron.php?cron_key=OrrbXhtfSEZ2NI7BlHjAPRtMT_ENAKaz68iH86Kl5wI > /tmp/job2.log
```

The files job1.log and job2.log will contain the output of your last run. I'm pretty sure you will see an error message in one of the files.

Comment: in job1.log file i get nothing. in job2.log file i get the html code source of my website

Comment: OK, job1.log got created that means the cronjob did trigger. I think that the URL is wrong.